# IE10 on Windows 7 page redirect not behaving as expected

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, internet-explorer-10

I am doing my testing on IE 10 standards mode. I have a `Login.aspx` page which is in Login directory (i.e `Login/Login.aspx`). I do `response.redirect` to a page `Default.aspx`which is a page in root directory(ie. `Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx",true);`). Also tried `~/Default.aspx` to navigate to root. But instead of going to Default.aspx control reaches to `Login.aspx`.

I do observe in IE developer's tool that it hits `Default.aspx` but transaction time < 1ms. I see it do not hit init/load event defined in `default.aspx`. Instead of redirect if I use Server.transfer it works but i want it to work with redirect only.

Also it works fine in my colleagues machine without making any change and also on latest firefox and chrome on my machine it works fine. It works fine on IE9 standard too on my machine but not on IE 10 standard.

Anyone happen to know if any setting or something I am missing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DestinationPageUrl parameter?

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" PasswordRecoveryText="Password forgotten?"
                    DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx"  
                    >
                </asp:Login>
```

Comment: I am not using Login control  and on click of a button i need to do redirect.thanks for the reply but i also want to know why this strange behavior happening on IE10 that too just with my machine.

Comment: Ok sorry, yeah that's very strange

Comment: I dont have entire idea yet how it worked. But after i made change to my webconfig's: cookieless="UseCookies" attribute for my login page, it worked. Earlier the value for cookieless was set as 'UseDeviceProfile'.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Antivirus settings, 
Got the same issue at work  ...

For another real life sample

go here

http://www.trojaner-board.de/133535-redirect-problem-ihavenet-ie10-win7.html

hope it'll help